# Finding occurrences of a method or variable in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, plugins

So I've been working with Visual Studio 2010 lately. While I'm not a huge fan of Eclipse, I do miss one feature: the fact that if you click on a function or variable in your code, it will mark all occurrences of that thing on the right frame of the text editor with a yellow or white rectangle. Does such a feature exist in Visual Studio? If not, is there a plugin out there that'll do this? I really don't want to resort to `Find All` every time I need to keep track where something is used.

Comment: Select something and hit `Shift+F12`

Comment: right click on a variable and select "Find All References"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ProductivityPowerTools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) is what you may need. There you have a bar where you can see a minimized view of all your code. If you click there you can also navigate your code. But if you click within your actual code on a member, all occurences of this member are shown in the map.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Highlight References](https://web.archive.org/web/20140725152827/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vseditor/archive/2009/09/22/searching-and-navigating-code-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) is feature in Visual Studio 2010 for C# and VB only. Any time you place the blinking caret on a symbol, Visual Studio will automatically highlight all instances of that symbol for you You can actually cycle through these highlighted references – just use Ctrl+Shift+up arrow and Ctrl+Shift+down arrow to move to the previous or next highlighted symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl-K then Ctrl-R, this will find all references to the method (or object, variable, etc.)

Comment: This may apply only to Productivity power tools, though.

Comment: Anyways, you can select the string you're looking for and press Ctrl+F3, then by F3, you can walk through all occurrences of the string too.